# Unable to import python module from same package

Tags: python, import, package

I'm currently writing a library in python. I have a package called `Selectors` as a sub-directory of the library. I am trying to implement a new module in the package, but when I try to import it I get the error:

```
NameError: name '_RaceSelector__ResultSelector' is not defined
```

My directory looks like this:

```
Selectors
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── SeasonSelector.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── Selector.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── race_selector.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── result_selector.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── season_selector.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── race_selector.py
│   ├── race_selector.pyc
│   ├── result_selector.py
│   ├── result_selector.pyc
│   ├── season_selector.py
│   ├── season_selector.pyc
│   ├── selector.py
│   └── selector.pyc
```

I want to use the modules in `race_selector.py`, here is that file:

```
from .selector import __Selector
from .result_selector import __ResultSelector

class RaceSelector(__Selector):

    data = []
    loaded_races = []
    header = []

    result_selector = __ResultSelector()
```

selector.py

```
import os
import csv

class __Selector:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.data_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../data/' + file_name + '.csv')
        self.raw_data = self.load_data()
        self.data = self.get_data()
```

result_selector.py

```
import os
from .selector import __Selector

class __ResultSelector(__Selector):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('results')
```

I am able to import `selector` just fine and works as intended, but result_selector produces the error.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the error comes from result_selector.py? Because it mentions `_RaceSelector`, which I can't spot in your code.

Comment: Plus, is there any reason to not have the different selectors in one common file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do the following:

```
result_selector = __ResultSelector()
```

Python searches for `_RaceSelector__ResultSelector` because there is 2 underscores.

As mentioned in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

```
If your class is intended to be subclassed, and you have attributes that you do not want subclasses to use, consider naming them with double leading underscores and no trailing underscores. This invokes Python's name mangling algorithm, where the name of the class is mangled into the attribute name. This helps avoid attribute name collisions should subclasses inadvertently contain attributes with the same name.
```

Comment: Wow. Didn't know that.

Comment: Neither did I. Very useful to know. Thank you!